# Почему программа пропускает условную конструкцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Выполняю задание по книге, уже есть готовая программа, которая выбирает случайное число и пользователь должен отгадать его. А мне нужно сделать так, чтобы кол-во попыток было ограничено. Я дописал if tries>5..... но программа пропускает этот момент.

```
# Guess My Number
#
# The computer picks a random number between 1 and 100
# The player tries to guess it and the computer lets
# the player know if the guess is too high, too low
# or right on the money

import random  

print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!")
print("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
print("Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.\n")

# set the initial values
the_number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
tries = 1

# guessing loop
while guess != the_number:
    if guess > the_number:
        print("Lower...")
    else:
        print("Higher...")

    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    tries += 1
    if tries > 5:
        print ("You couldn't guess the number.")
        break
    elif guess==the_number:
        print("You guessed it!  The number was", the_number)
        print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!\n")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: Не может такого быть!

Comment: Т.е. в каком смысле не может быть? Не может быть такого кода или не может быть того, чтобы конструкция не читалась?

Comment: Просто я посмотрел на одном сайте с ответами, у нас с автором того кода различие только в описании игры.

Comment: Не может быть, что пропускает. Я запустил код и все работает. Только попыток, как и ожидалось, 6. А почему - предлагаю сообразить самостоятельно.

Comment: Т.е. моя "добавка" к коду правильная?

Comment: Мне пока не важно кол-во попыток, я чуть ниже на ответ дал комментарий.

Comment: Непонятно о какой добавке речь. Код рабочий.

Comment: Изначально был дан автором книги код игры, а в задании он говорит, что читателю нужно "улучшить" эту игру, добавив в нее ограничение по попыткам. Я добавил.

Comment: Вы попробовали запустить эту игру через cmd? Вам выдает сообщение о том, что Вы не угадали число после того, как Вы сделали 6 попыток?

Comment: да. Как вы запускаете код?

Comment: Извините, я проверил по ответам на это задание из Интернета, скопировал код, вставил, запустил и у меня та же проблема, что и с моим кодом. Получается безграничное кол-во попыток. А код я запускаю так - 1. Создаю текстовый файл, меняю его расширение на .py 2. Перетаскиваю файл в Sublime 3. Пишу код, сохраняю его 4. Двойным кликом запускаю этот файл, он запускается через программу Python

Answer (score 2):

Пятерку на четверку поменяй: 
if tries > 4: #Здесь указано больше N, следовательно вырубалось после 6-й попытки

Comment: Привет, я уже увидел правку, но не думаю, что это что-то изменит. По факту это должно поменять только количество возможных попыток, пока это мне не важно, хоть одна попытка будет дана игроку, хоть 7. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы эти попытки ВООБЩЕ были.

Comment: Не понял тебя. Что ты имеешь ввиду под "Вообще были"? У меня работает, и выбивает после 5-й попытки фразу "нажмите энтер для завершения"

Comment: Ну у меня есть исходный код. Это небольшая игра. И мне дали задание. Нужно сделать так, чтобы было ОГРАНИЧЕННОЕ количество попыток, я вроде как правильно написал код, а при запуске в cmd у меня пропускается та часть кода, где я описал существование этих попыток. Вот я и говорю, что для начала надо сделать так, чтобы эти "попытки" заработали, а потом уже поменять количество, эту пять я вообще из головы взял, и я понимаю, что кол-во попыток будет 6

Comment: В чем выражается "пропускается та часть кода"? У минимум двух человек ваш код работает, как и задумано.

Comment: в cmd выдает после 5 неудачных попыток строку: "You couldn't guess the number."

Comment: Спасибо, что проверили. Значит либо я как-то неправильно код запускаю, либо что-то с командной строкой у меня.

Comment: А как сюда кинуть скриншот? На фотохостинг можно залить и ссылку скинуть?

Comment: Попробуй скопировать сначала в Sublime 3, сохрани как *.py, а потом запусти.

Comment: У меня похоже что-то с текстовиком случилось нехорошее, создал новый, всё заработало, спасибо вам огромное.

Comment: незачто, удачи!

Answer (score 1):

Выходим из цикла если угадали число или превысили кол-во попыток. Позже проверяем причину.

```
# Guess My Number
#
# The computer picks a random number between 1 and 100
# The player tries to guess it and the computer lets
# the player know if the guess is too high, too low
# or right on the money

import random  

print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!")
print("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
print("Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.\n")

# set the initial values
the_number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
tries = 1
MAX_TRIES = 5

# guessing loop
while tries < MAX_TRIES:
    if guess == the_number:
        break

    if guess > the_number:
        print("Lower...")
    else:
        print("Higher...")

    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    tries += 1


if guess == the_number:
    print("You guessed it!  The number was", the_number)
    print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!\n")
else:
    print("You couldn't guess the number.")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```